# Display list into textbox

Tags: vb.net, list

I am trying to add values onto a list and display them all in a label in a list format. Currently from what I can tell my code is only picking up the last value clicked and not adding all values clicked to the list. I've tried modifying the for loop at the bottom but this current code is the best I could get it working and it's still far off. Is there an easy fix?

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim Cars As Integer = 0
    Dim Weight As Integer = 0
    Dim CarList As New List(Of String)

    Private Sub BtnBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBox.Click
        'Adds 1 to total and 65000kgs to the weight
        Cars = Cars + 1
        lblTotalCars.Text = Cars

        Weight = Weight + 65000
        lblTotalWeight.Text = Weight

        CarList.Add("Box")
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnContainer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnContainer.Click
        'Adds 1 to total and 30000kgs to the weight
        Cars = Cars + 1
        lblTotalCars.Text = Cars

        Weight = Weight + 30000
        lblTotalWeight.Text = Weight

        CarList.Add("Container")

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnHopper_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHopper.Click
        'Adds 1 to total and 51300 to the weight
        Cars = Cars + 1
        lblTotalCars.Text = Cars

        Weight = Weight + 51300
        lblTotalWeight.Text = Weight

        CarList.Add("Hopper")
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnRefridge_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefridge.Click
        'Adds 1 to total and 59400 to the weight
        Cars = Cars + 1
        lblTotalCars.Text = Cars

        Weight = Weight + 59400
        lblTotalWeight.Text = Weight

        CarList.Add("Refridgerator")
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnTank_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTank.Click
        'Adds 1 to total and 45200 to the weight
        Cars = Cars + 1
        lblTotalCars.Text = Cars

        Weight = Weight + 45200
        lblTotalWeight.Text = Weight

        CarList.Add("Tank")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For i As Integer = 0 To CarList.Count - 1
            lbl.Text = CarList(i) + vbCrLf 'Tried this to create the list format but code only displaying last selected value
        Next i
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `lbl.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, CarList)` (with `lbl.AutoSize = true`)

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having a problem is that, in your loop, the `Label` text is being overwritten on each iteration. The simple addition of an ampersand (`&`) in front of the `=` adds the new text to the existing text. The long way to write it would be

```
lbl.Text = lbl.Text & CarList(i) & vbCrLf
```

Like the `&=` you can also use the shortcut `+=` for addition. I showed this in the `BtnTank.Click` method.

Do turn on `Option Strict` and keep it on for all your projects. The `.Text` property of `Control`s is a `String`. `Cars` and `Weight` are `Integers`. The `.ToString` method corrects this.

```
Dim Cars As Integer = 0
Dim Weight As Integer = 0
Dim CarList As New List(Of String)

Private Sub BtnTank_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTank.Click
    Cars += Cars
    lblTotalCars.Text = Cars.ToString
    Weight += 45200
    lblTotalWeight.Text = Weight.ToString

    CarList.Add("Tank")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To CarList.Count - 1
        lbl.Text &= CarList(i) & vbCrLf
    Next i
End Sub
```

The code provided by @Jimi will also work saving you from having to write the loop. I keep the code in your format to show where it was going wrong.